# Selenium get all child nodes

Tags: c#, selenium

You guys, I have a HTML like this:

```
    <li class="selectBox-selected selectBox-hover">
       <a rel="0">Select payee type</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a rel="1">Injured Worker</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
     <a rel="2">Employer</a>
    </li>
   <li class="">
     <a rel="4">Creditor</a>
   </li>
```

This is code to get all the above option into the list:

```
  List<IWebElement> lstOption = ConstantsLib.driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//li[. = 'selectBox-selected selectBox-hover']/following-sibling::li")).ToList();
```

Actually It does not work. I dont know if Where I am wrong.
Please help me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your XPath to:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'selectBox-selected selectBox-hover')]/following-sibling::li
```

Comment: Perhaps explain what the XPath actually means, to aid in education and sharing knowledge.

Comment: I think it's clear from the example, the intent is the same as the OP xpath, just showing how to properly select a class.